# Vue3 v-text-field transition

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have an app bar that has a v-text-box that I am trying to animate a slide in/slide out effect when I click a button. I have that working the problem I am facing is the button itself is sliding in and out in addition to the text box, I want the button to remain static. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
<template>

  <v-app-bar 
  style="position:fixed;  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.141));"
  :elevation="5">

    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <v-app-bar-title>
    
        Name
      </v-app-bar-title>
      <v-toolbar-items>
          <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
          <v-btn variant="text">News</v-btn>
          <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
          <v-btn variant="text">Blog</v-btn>
          <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
          <v-btn variant="text">Music</v-btn>
          <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </template>

    
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    
    <Transition>
      <v-text-field 
      density="compact"
      variant="outlined"
      single-line
      hide-details
      class="textbox"
      v-if="showSearch"
      ></v-text-field>
    </Transition>  

    <v-btn icon @click="showSearch = !showSearch">
      <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    
  </v-app-bar>

</template>
<style>
 .textbox {
    max-width: 400px ;
  }

 .v-toolbar-title {
      margin-left: 60px;
      margin-right: 60px;
    }


  .v-enter-active,
  .v-leave-active{
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .v-enter-from{
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .v-enter-to{
    margin-left: 10%;
  }

  .v-leave-from{
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .v-leave-to{
    margin-left: 100%;
  }

</style>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  const showSearch = ref(false);


    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation works by increasing the left margin until the element is pushed out of view. Since the button is to the right of the input, it is also pushed out of the view. When the input is removed at the end of the transition, the button reappears in its position.

A simple solution would be to transform the element's width instead of moving it out:

```css
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.v-enter-from {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
.v-enter-to {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.v-leave-from {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}
.v-leave-to {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

When you search the web for "css reveal animation", you'll find tons of more complex animations